# Layout disappears with same html/css coding

Tags: html, css

Layout disappears with same html/css coding. you can see layout misaligned on wrong page but with same html/css coding it works perfectly on other page, check right page.

Problem occurs due to first  of main section get 938px width instead of 5px, i try to add width, max-width by css but no luck. Check screenshot.

Right page- http://www.waterloostructures.net/garages/2-story-modular-liberty.php

Wrong page- http://www.waterloostructures.net/garages/2-story-keystone-cf.php

[image]

Comment: avoid using tables for this task, consider using divs. your layout is messed up because of the tables.

Comment: Yes, using Div is better than Table. But that is a old site & just 2 page with same problem. That will be easy to fix that issue instead of re-code full page.

Comment: yes I understand, one fix can be as mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, then to fix this you can add one empty `<td></td>` in your second tr of the lower one table

Yes it is working.. this is what I am suggesting:

```
<tr><td></td>   <!-- notice empty td elems -->
<td>


<!-- ZiffTalk tag starts--><map name="199911">
...
</td></tr>
```

OR 
add `colspan="2"` to the column

Comment: because the problem was that the first row of lower table had 2 columns, second row had one, so it got displaced. Try it out.